# Block grid shows horizontal scroll bar in Foundation

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, stylesheet, zurb-foundation

I am just starting to learn Foundation (from previous messy css experience). I am trying to do a full screen block grid of 4 col images per row. I have this to make the row full width:

```
.row
  max-width: 100%
```

Here is the code:

```
<nav class='top-bar'>
  <ul class='title-area'>
    <li class='name'>
      <h1>
        <a href='#'>
          My Website
        </a>
      </h1>
    </li>
    <li class='toggle-topbar menu-icon'>
      <a href='#'>
        <span>menu</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <section class='top-bar-section'></section>
</nav>
<div class='row'>
  <ul class='small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4'>
    <li>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Thumbnail' />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Thumbnail' />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Thumbnail' />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src='http://placehold.it/500x500&text=Thumbnail' />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am getting annoying horizontal scroll bar. See below screenshot

[image]

I know it is the margin below:

```
@media only screen
[class*="block-grid-"]
  margin: 0 -0.625em;
```

But do I suppose to override it? It doesn't feel right (seem like a **hack**). How do I use Foundation properly to display **block grid with full screen**? It's a simple layout requirement.

Comment: width issue comming please check your width css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the docs explaining [the Foundation grid they already use the `box-sizing: border-box` star hack](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)

Since the `.row` containing your `block-grid`has a set max-width of 100% it's overflowing the screen width. Typically, elements in the grid would be nested in `.rows` with defined `max-widths` and also contained within defined column sizes.

You can simply just do the hacky thing as you deeply **fear** and adjust the margin:

`@media only screen
[class*="block-grid-"]
  margin: 0 2em;`

Or you can just contain your `.block-grid` with a container `<div class="large-12 columns">`.

Six of one half-a-dozen of the other I'd say. If you're afraid of screwing up the grid layout, you can use a conditional class on the body tag so that your customized `block-grid` only effects the pages that you want.

Comment: This works perfectly: `block-grid` with a container `<div class="large-12 columns">`

Comment: I've been having this issue and was fixing it with awful `padding` hacks that I had no idea why they even fixed (or what was causing the issue)... still don't know why in my case the issue occurs but thanks for your solution, @tnog

Answer (score 0):

take a look of this [demo by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

this might be helpful else can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not want to wrap their block grid within the standard row/column grid, simply hide the overflow on your block grid's parent element. Here's a superfluous code demonstration.

```
(html)
<div class="block-grid-parent">
  <ul class="block-grid">
    ...

(css)
.block-grid-parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```